# How can I filter a view by "has translation"?

Tags: 7, views

Filter a view by "Current user language" creates an empty div when missing translation. This is problematic because it breaks my layout. See the below image for my criteria.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested but you could probably add the filter "Node translation: Child translation" to your view. Together with the current user language fiter this could work. Description is: "Content that is a translation of a source translation."

Answer (score 0):

Well this can easily be solved by adding a "**No results behavior**"  to be a global: text area, global:view or anything you have to say when it's empty.

just add whatever the HTML you want to display there. this can be a workaround for the problem that you are having.